# Getting sub-shapes on Layer with CreateSelection

Tags: vba, visio

Is it possible to use the Page.CreateSelection method to return a selection of all the shapes on a page on a given layer, INCLUDING those that are within groups?

It's easy to get the shapes that are at the page level:
    ActivePage.CreateSelection( visSelTypeByLayer , 0 , "GivenLayer" )

but it doesn't seem to work with groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CreateSelection can also be used on a group shape to get sub-shapes, but I do not think that you can create a selection of all page shapes and group sub-shapes in a single line. You would need to build up the selection from many CreateSelection calls (one at page, and one for each group shape in the page, etc )